# Node Forever Affects App Display (Style and Routes)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, forever, nodemon

I am currently trying to make my app server run indefinitely with forever and nodemon. To do so, I am using the following command:

```
forever -c nodemon --exitcrash app.js
```

the problem is that the presence of forever module seems to affect the display of my app. Namely, whenever I run the app using forever, my login window styles are changed and the entire thing is shifted to the left side of the window. What is more, some of the app routes stop working. On the other hand, whenever I use a simple `npm start` or `nodemon command`, it works as expected.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? How could I make the server run continuously and not mess with the app itself?

P.S. It may be useful to mention that for some reason, my app only works upon running `npm start` and does not work properly when `node app.js` is run. I am unsure why that happens.

Comment: Just a thought, why do you use forever and nodemon together? I mean nodemon is for development so when you change any file your app automatically restarts. Forever is meant for production so when your app crashes it restarts it. What does your npm start script look like?

Comment: I am still in development mode so I was just trying to learn how to achieve persistence. That said, I shall consider other prudent ways of doing so.